# Listing files from folder and creating data frame

Tags: r

HI i am trying to combine data frames one after other

```
df1                                df1  
name    address                     age        Gender
A         NY                         23        M
B         CA                         22        F
                                     33        M
                                     39        F
```

I am trying to combine both the data frames with below code which is not giving required output

```
folder <- "path/"      # path to folder shows multiple .csv files
file_list <- list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.csv") # create list of all .csv files in folder

all_df <- 
  do.call("cbind", 
          lapply(file_list, function(x)  read.csv(paste(folder, x, sep=''), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
```

O/p

```
all_df
 name    address   age        Gender
    A         NY    23        M
    B         CA    22        F
                    33        M
                    39        F
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cbind.fill` from `rowr`

```
library(rowr)
cbind.fill(df1, df2, fill="")
#   name address age Gender
#1    A      NY  23      M
#2    B      CA  22      F
#3               33      M
#4               39      F
```

---

If we want to modify the original code of the OP

```
do.call(cbind.fill, 
      lapply(file_list, function(x)  read.csv(paste(folder, x, sep=''), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
```

Comment: thanks akrun for your answer , How can we combine before creating data frames i.e while reading

Comment: yes that is wat i tried ,nice to know cbin.fill..Thanks

Comment: Instead of `paste` you can use `?file.path`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas  Thank you.  Nice to see you here